# Eledmac: hyperlink to table of contents generates additional pages

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, eledmac

I'm writing a critical edition that includes a link to the table of contents on each page. When I do this in eledmac, additional pages appear in the vicinity of the table:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{eledmac}

\title{Example}
\author{Name}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle

\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{centering}
\copyright \the\year\\
\end{centering}

\clearpage
\phantomsection
\hypertarget{contents}{}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{Here's a text}
\section{Section one}
\lipsum
\hyperlink{contents}{Contents}
\end{document}
```

Furthermore, the link to the toc lands on the extra page preceding the toc.The document compiles perfectly when `\usepackage{eledmac}`is commented out, with the table landing on the nearest odd numbered page.

This looks like I'm missing something basic.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). I can't notice that behavior. Try updating your packages.

Comment: @karlkoeller An update of the most recent version of eledmac did the trick. An easy fix. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to an old package. Updating it the issue is solved.